# Итерация словаря

Tags: python, словари

Не могу понять, есть словарь:

```
 {'time': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 11, 13, 22, 4)}
 {'time': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 11, 13, 43, 36)}
 {'time': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 11, 13, 55, 41)}
```

Вывожу через цикл `for`, на выходе совершенно в разнобой сортировка, не так как в словаре.

Comment: Не совсем корректный код в вопросе. Приведены 3 отдельных словаря, а не один по которому идёт for.

Comment: да, виноват.Словарь внутри словари, как их отсортировать корректно по значению например

Answer (score 8):

В python словари не хранят порядок добавления элементов. И выводят данные в [произвольном порядке](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) (зависит от порядка добавления, удаления элементов, метода хеширования, способа хранения словаря в памяти, версии Python интерпретатора).

Если нужен словарь который будет хранить порядок элементов нужно использовать `collections.OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 4):

Как уже было сказано, словарь не хранит элементы упорядоченно (т.е. элементы не упорядочены по значениям ключей). Есть `OrderedDict`, но он просто помнит порядок добавления элементов, но никак не сортирует их (начиная с Python 3.6 обычный словарь также помнит порядок добавления). Чтобы вывести элементы по возрастанию ключа, можно, например, отсортировать ключи, и ими уже пройтись по словарю:

```
from random import randint
d = {randint(0, 100): randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(10)}
# Пример: {80: 680, 33: 669, 50: 692, 91: 445, 20: 138, 38: 517, 24: 37, 27: 715, 78: 516, 59: 797}
for key in sorted(d):
    print(key, d[key])
```

Пример результата:

```
20 138 
24 37  
27 715 
33 669 
38 517 
50 692 
59 797 
78 516 
80 680 
91 445
```

Еще один вариант: превратить обычный словарь в `OrderedDict` с элементами, отсортированными по значению ключа (новые элементы, правда, будут все равно добавляться в "конец" словаря):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
# Пусть d - словарь
d = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[0]))
```

Суть процедуры: из исходного словаря берутся пары ключ - значение, кладутся в список, отсортированный по первому значению в парах (т.е. по ключу первоначального словаря), потом полученный список превращается в `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score -1):

```
dict_arg = {'name': 'my name', 'company': 'my company', 'adress': 'my adress'}


# Можно попробовать так:
# Пример из жизни - собирал строку из словаря, с сохранением порядка по его же маске:

', '.join(['{0}: {1}'.format(key, value) for (key, value) in sorted(dict_arg.items(), key=lambda x: x in dict_arg.keys())])
```